# Android studio is not running

Tags: android, android-studio

In the first run, it asked for adding SDK add-on list. For that I switched off firewall. Still after that it is not starting. That loading screen( box in which andriod studio is there with green loading line) is loaded till last few. It is not going further even waiting for hours.

Comment: You can look in `$(HOME)/.AndroidStudio2.2/system/log` for the log files. These may give you some idea of what the problem is. Note that `$(HOME)` represents your user directory and the Android Studio version number might be different depending on which version you have installed.

Comment: Thank you for your effort but that's not solving my problem still. Is there any requirement for adding environment variable manually?

Comment: "Is there any requirement for adding environment variable manually?" I don't understand what you are asking. What environment variable? For what purpose?

Comment: It might be best to start over and follow the instructions at https://developer.android.com/studio/install.html. If you continue to have problems edit this question or post a new one describing the exact steps you took and what problems occurred.

Comment: I was asking for ANDROID_HOME & JAVA_HOME like variables. Is there any other variables do I need to include in my environment variables in advanced system settings.

Comment: What OS are you running?